# Matrix of epimorphism - is it possible that matrix is diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:V\to V$ will be epimporphism.
Is there exists base such that $f$ has matrix which is diagonalisable ?

Can anyone help me solve it ? I can't deal with it.

Comment: $f$ is also injective; it can be diagonalizable or not. There's nothing special in being surjective, with respect to diagonalization.

Comment: Ok, I know that it is also monomorphism - so we have isomorphism. My task is to answer: It there exists such base that matrix of $f$ is diagonal.

Comment: This is the same as asking if every invertible matrix is diagonalizable, which is false. Consider the linear map $f(x,y)=(x+y,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being $f$ an epimorphism has nothing to do with being diagonalizable. Since $f$ must also be injective, your question is whether any isomorphism is diagonalizable: this is false.

Consider the map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$
f\colon\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}x+y\\y\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is an epimorphism, but is not diagonalizable.

Comment: my question is: Is there exists some **base** such that **matrix** of $f$ in this base is diagonal. I can't understand how works your explanation.

Comment: @HaskellFun Your request is equivalent to the matrix of $f$ with respect to *any* base is diagonalizable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, from what you know that each matrix (any base) of your $f$ is not diagonalizable ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Because that map is not diagonalizable; it's the simplest example and everybody doing linear algebra should know it.